# OctoberCMS Media Finder. Invalid Security Token

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, octobercms

i have an issue with the OctoberCMS media finder. I am trying to select an MP4 file from the media finder, but I get the error "Invalid Security Token". It lets me select images, but not the video. The server allows me to upload video to the media area using the uploader, just not select it in the finder. Any ideas on how I can resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with "Invalid Security Token", you can disable this security enhancement in /config/cms.php
`'enableCsrfProtection' => false,`

Comment: That doesn't solve why csrf protection doesn't work